# How to make sure the user type "@yahoo" or"@gmail" in an edit text?

Tags: android, eclipse, account

How to make sure the user type "@yahoo" or"@gmail" in an edit text(email) and intent the information to the next page.
What I want to do is: make a page for the user to open a fake account and put in all the information and then, intent all the information to the next page. Make the user feels like he/she had opened an account. And now my question is: how to confirm that the user had type in "xxx@xxx.com" in the edit text to prevent he/she knows it's fake.
Any kinds of solutions will help.

Comment: Why do every one dislike my question...

Comment: This site is great because it's NOT a "please give me code" site, rather it works well when you have a clear question preferably with some example code. Requests for complete solutions are generally frowned upon.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by checking "yahoo" or "gmail" or ... in the string you get from the edit text like this:

```
 if (strMessage.contains("@gmail.com") || strMessage.contains("@yahoo.com"){
//Do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: Thx. I won't do anything bad

Comment: How to check the "yahoo" or "gmail"? Sorry, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: strMessage.contains("gmail") or strMessage.contains("yahoo") or strMessage.contains("whatever you want")

Comment: So how to set a check change on the edit text?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("Your xxx@xxx.com").matches();
}
```

this will return boolean

Answer (score 0):

First set check to your "email" or "gmail", then use an if statement

```
if (editText.contains("@")){

 Your code

}
```